# how to query hdb dynamic enough such that byClause, selectCols, whereCols are dynamically build and then query hdb

Tags: kdb

how to query hdb dynamic enough such that byClause, selectCols, whereCols are dynamically build and then query hdb

```
n: 30;  // Number of rows in the table
tab:([] date: .z.d - n?30; ranks: n?100; sym: n?`AAPL`MSFT`GOOGL; group_name_symbol:n?`US_HOLIDAY`SPCL_CAL_DATE ; group_name_string:n?("FIRST_3rd_FRI";"QTR_3rd_FRI";"FIRST_6rd_FRI") ;price: "f"$n?100.5; recv_time: n?10:00:00.000 + n?10000000; is_active: "b"$n?1 0);
```

[image]

Now, I want to accept args from user say like

```
//1. user can pass syms as symbol list or ` for all
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`GOOGL`MSFT;1b)  //get only 2 syms -> select from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`;1b)    //all syms -> select from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), is_active=args[`valid]

//2. user can pass byCols, will will do the groupby
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`;1b;`sym)    //groupby 1 cols -> select by sym from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`;1b;`date`sym`group_name_symbol)    //groupby 3 cols -> select by date,sym,group_name_symbol from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`GOOGL`MSFT;1b;`sym)   //groupby 1 cols and filter for sym column -> select by sym from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]

//3. select desired cols only -> select col1, col2 from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`selCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`GOOGL`MSFT;1b;`date`rank)  //select only 2 cols `date`rank along with filters ->  select date,rank from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`selCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`;1b;`sym`rank)      //select sym,rank from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), is_active=args[`valid]
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols`selCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`;1b;`sym;`sym`rank)    
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols`selCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`;1b;`date`sym`group_name_symbol;`sym`rank)
(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`GOOGL`MSFT;1b;`sym)   //groupby 1 cols and filter for sym column -> select by sym from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]
```

So user will call the funtion like

```
get_hdb_data[(`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols`selCols)!(2010.01.01;2010.01.31;`ABC`XYZ;1b;`date`sym`group_name_symbol;`sym`rank)]

which will be equivalent to 
select selCols by byCols from tab where date within (args[`startDate];args[`endDate]), sym in args[`syms], is_active=args[`valid]
```

If syms is `then it means all syms / dont filter for sym if` is passed
If byCols is `then it means all syms / dont filter for byCols if` is passed
If selCols is `then it means all syms / dont filter for selCols if` is passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to suggest something concrete, but you can use below function as a template

```
{
  // where clause
  wc: ();
  if[`startDate in key x; wc,: enlist(>=;`date;x`startDate)];
  if[`endDate in key x; wc,: enlist(<=;`date;x`endDate)];
  if[`syms in key x; wc,: enlist(in;`sym;enlist x`syms)];
  if[`valid in key x; wc,: enlist(=;`is_active;x`valid)];
  // functional select
  ?[tab;wc;{x!x}x`byCols;{x!x}x`selCols]
}`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols`selCols! 
 (2023.06.01;2024.01.31;`AAPL`MSFT;1b;`date`sym`group_name_symbol;`sym`ranks)
```

And 3 useful suggestions

1. Building where clause is the most complicated part.
2. I would pass dictionaries of column names-values as `selCols` and `byCols`. Especially, when aggregation is required. E.g., to get max rank by symbol you could define `selCols` as  `` enlist[`maxRank]!enlist(max;`ranks) `` and `byCols` as `` enlist[`sym]!enlist[`sym] ``

Like below

```
{
  // where clause
  wc: ();
  if[`startDate in key x; wc,: enlist(>=;`date;x`startDate)];
  if[`endDate in key x; wc,: enlist(<=;`date;x`endDate)];
  if[`syms in key x; wc,: enlist(in;`sym;enlist x`syms)];
  if[`valid in key x; wc,: enlist(=;`is_active;x`valid)];
  // functional select
  ?[tab;wc;x`byCols;x`selCols]
}`startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols`selCols!(2023.06.01;2024.01.31;`AAPL`MSFT;1b;enlist[`sym]!enlist[`sym];enlist[`maxRank]!enlist(max;`ranks))
```

3. To avoid grouping and get `selCols` with only filters applied set `byCols` to `0b`. So parameter list be  `` `startDate`endDate`syms`valid`byCols`selCols!(2023.06.01;2024.01.31;`AAPL`MSFT;1b;0b;`sym`ranks!`sym`ranks) ``

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It really helped me in formatting and getting close to my answer. Yeah I agree with your suggestions and I am working on my get function and enhancing it.. which is almost ready now and giving me what I was looking for. Thank you very much again! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at functional qSQL (https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/) which allows this level of customization.

Comment: I had gone though it and so far I got below, how do I get only last or first value in selectCols if byCols is used. Something like ```(enlist`expiration_date)!enlist (last;`expiration_date)``` I want all selectCols to have first or last (selectCols!selectCols)
```selectCols:`date`root`norm_sym`expiration_date; ```
```byCols:`norm_sym`root;```
```?[res1; ();byCols!byCols;(selectCols!selectCols)]```